# navigate(-1) Returns to the Google homepage

Tags: reactjs

In the site I am building, it is defined that the person who logs in to the home page and has not yet logged in with his account, then he is automatically transferred to a login in a defined login.

I use react-router-dom with useNavigate

And I do it like this:

```
const navigate = useNavigate ();
navigate (-1, {replace: true});
```

When the customer enters the main page and then is transferred to login everything is fine
The problem when he immediately logs in is returned to the previous page which is the Google page

Is it possible to check if there is a previous page and only then move it to the previous page?

Desired:

```
if(navigate (-1)) {
navigate (-1);
}else {navigate ("/");}
```

And in case it is not moved to the main page

Answer (score 0):

you can use user state to conditionaly render certain pages

App.js

```
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

<Route path="main">
    {user?.registered ? //first condition
        <>
           <Route path="" element={<Page1 />} />
           <Route path="profile-user" element={<ProfileUser />} />
           <Route path="settings" element={user?.settings && <Settings />} /> //another condition here
           <Route path="profile-public">
                <Route path=":user" element={<ProfilePublic />} />
           </Route>
        </>
    : user && user?.registered === false ? //second condition
        <Route path="" element={<CreateAccount/>} />
    :
        <Route path="" element={<WelcomePage/>} /> //default page
    }
 </Route>
 <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/main" />} /> //redirect all pages that don't exist under domain to homepage
```

of course you still need to use Routes and BrowserRouter to wrap these

Comment: react will simply switch you to the page that meets the condition, for example if you set user to be "null" you will get logout and will be moved to WelcomePage instantly

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself correctly I use with Google Translate
I wanted that when the customer enters a page that must be logged in then it goes to the login screen and then it is moved to the page that it accesses before logging in like this:
deshbord> login> deshbord

Comment: you can save the url when entering the page with a state like so `setUrl(window.location.href)` (dashboard page), put the state in the parent component, the parent of dashboard and login can be App.js, pass the url state as props from App.js to login page and check the state if url === "http://,,localhost:3000/dashboard" then navigate(-1)